# Unable to get session contents in second function

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having some issues with sessions.

In the first function `queue`, I save the session `entries` I can print this out from this function, so I can see its being set correctly.

In the function `remove`, I try and save this entries session into a variable and I get the error that `entries` is an `undefined index`.

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
function queue() 
{
    session_start();

    $status = 'Awaiting Moderation';
    $channel = '1';

    // Find all entries in 'Gallery' channel with 'Awaiting Moderation' status
    $this->EE->db->select('entry_id')
                 ->from('exp_channel_titles')
                 ->where('status', $status)
                 ->where('channel_id', $channel);

    $query = $this->EE->db->get();      
    $entries = $query->result_array();

    $entries_count = count($entries);

    // Set count
    $_SESSION['entries_count'] = $entries_count;    

    // If entries found
    if ($entries_count > 0)
    {
        // Flatten entry ids array
        $entriesFlat = array();
        array_walk_recursive($entries, function($a) use (&$entriesFlat) { $entriesFlat[] = $a; });

        $entriesSerial = serialize($entriesFlat);

        // Save in session
        $_SESSION['entries'] = $entriesSerial;
    }

}

function remove()
{
    session_start();

    // Get session data + save into variable
    $entries = $_SESSION['entries'];

}
```

Comment: You should use session_start() at first line.

Comment: Hi. I am using session_start() on each first line of each function, is that not right?

Comment: Calling session_start() once at the top of each script (not within a function) should be enough.

Comment: This has made no difference. Still showing undefined index.

Comment: If you are using codeigniter then why are you not using session library? read this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Are you certain $entries_count is greater than 0?  You only need to call session_start() once -- I recommend that at the bootstrap phase of your app.  In your remove function, I would do: if (isset($_SESSION['entries'])) { // do stuff here }

Comment: Use session class of codeigniter and change in $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one session and it should be at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using codeigniter why not use codeigniter session and then autoload library and then you can do code like below.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('entries_count', $entries_count);
```

To Get Data

```
$this->session->userdata('entries_count');
```

And

```
$this->session->set_userdata('entries', $entriesSerial);
```

To Get Data

```
$this->session->userdata('entries');

// Example

if ($this->session->userdata('entries') > 0)
{
```

User Guide

CI2 http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

CI3: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, there's not need to declare 'session' again at 'remove()' function..

2ndly to set session contents you have to write  :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('entries_count', $entries_count);
```

Instead of

```
$_SESSION['entries'] = $entriesSerial;
```

Save it in session

To get session contents you've to write:

```
$entries_count = $this->session->userdata('entries_count');
```

Get session data + save into variable

Then you can write the condition like:

```
if ($entries_count > 0) {

}
```

Similarly, you've to write

```
$this->session->set_userdata('entries', $entriesSerial);
```

To save in session instead of

```
$_SESSION['entries'] = $entriesSerial;
```

And

```
$entries = $this->session->userdata('entries');
```

To Get session data + save into variable